# How do I configure ASP.NET to show a custom error page, but still return the correct statusCode (i.e.404)

Tags: asp.net, iis, config

How can I configure ASP.NET/IIS to show custom error pages (i.e. a nice friendly error page), but to still return a 404/500 status code so that google does not try to index the page?

I have tried setting the Response.StatusCode to 404, but then the nice error page does not show anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not tried this yet, but this page describes the exact issue and how to solve it. ASP.NET's way of returning 302's for error pages is a known SEO "issue".

http://weblogs.asp.net/paxer/archive/2010/05/31/asp-net-http-404-and-seo.aspx